# Minigame blackjack

Tags: c#, blackjack

For 2 players in a console app the game draws numbers from 1 to 10 instead of cards. With a do-while loop asking the question, whether you want to choose a card. I have a problem with giving the right word after the **answer not,** because then the loop should be broken and when it gives break it asks still and how to return it exits the program at the end the program says who won.

```
`enter code here` Console.WriteLine("now the first player's turn");
        int number = 0;
        Random r = new Random();

        ` do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Are you downloading the card?");
            string odp = Console.ReadLine();
            switch (odp)
            {
                case "yes":
                    int rInt = r.Next(1, 10);
                    number += rInt;
                    Console.WriteLine(number);
                    break;
                case "not":
                    ?

            }
            if (number >= 22)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The player 1 lost with {0} pkt", number);
                break;
            }


        } while (number < 22);
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem and what have you tried so far? Can you share some code?

Comment: Please edit your question with the code instead of posting it as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version that seems to do what you need with your current code.
I add a boolean condition (bool continuePlaying) to stay inside the "do loop" or not.

```
    using System;
    
    namespace BlackJack
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
            Console.WriteLine("First player's turn");

            int number = 0;
            Random random = new Random();
            bool continuePlaying = true;

            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Are you downloading the card? [Y]es/[N]o");
                string userAnswer = Console.ReadLine();

                switch (userAnswer.ToLower())
                {
                    case "y":
                        int randomNumber = random.Next(1, 10);
                        number += randomNumber;

                        Console.WriteLine($"Your total of points is: {number}");
                        continuePlaying = true;
                        break;

                    case "n":
                        Console.WriteLine($"Your total of points is: {number}");
                        continuePlaying = false; // Stop playing
                        break;

                    default:
                        Console.Clear();
                        Console.WriteLine("Please choose [Y]es or [N]o");
                        continuePlaying = true;
                        break;
                }
            } while (number < 22 && continuePlaying == true);
            
            if (number <= 21)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"You end the game with a total of {number} points");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"The player 1 lost with {number} points");
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```